# GroupBy column and then Sum

Tags: sql, eloquent

I have some data,

```
Material           Stock Level       Confirmed Stock        Price
FP1001             100               27                     1.25
FP1001             187               84                     1.36
FP1002             19                2                      0.76
```

I need to be able to groupBy "Material" and then SUM the "Stock Level" and "Confirmed Stock" level, so the resulting collection would be:

```
FP1001             287               111                    (blank)
```

What's the easiest and fastest way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why no FP1002 in the result?

Answer (score 2):

you only need a simple groupping, any google result would tell you that. btw, here's code

```
  SELECT [Material], SUM([Stock Level]), SUM([Confirmed Stock])
  FROM [YourTable]
  GROUP BY [Material]
```